# Is it possible to use vector index 1 with list element 1, index 2 with element 2, etc?

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a set of numerical coordinates representing the start and end positions of a vector, which are to be checked against a table of contiguous regions to see which ones they are present in. For each pair of start and end positions there is a **different** region table to check against. The numerical coordinates are currently stored in a pair of equally indexed vectors (so that starts[1] pairs with ends[1]), which would be checked against table[[1]]. I already have this down with a for loop, but am wondering if there is a faster way to do it (using some member of the apply family probably/possibly) considering the index for the vectors and elements of the list is always the same.

It's probably easier to understand with an example:

```
starts <- c(7, 163); ends <- c(15, 165)

df1 <- data.frame(seq(from = 1, to = 91, by = 10), 
    seq(from = 10, to = 100, by = 10), paste0('Region', 1:10))

df2 <- data.frame(seq(from = 101, to = 191, by = 10), 
    seq(from = 110, to = 200, by = 10), paste0('Region', 1:10))

mylist <- list(df1, df2)


# With a for loop, I could iterate through as follows:

for (n in 1:length(starts)) {

  regions <- which(starts[n] >= mylist[[n]][, 1] & starts[n] <= mylist[[n]][, 2]):which(ends[n] >= mylist[[n]][, 1] & ends[n] <= mylist[[n]][, 2])

  print(mylist[[n]][regions, 3])

}
```

While the above works fine, I'll be running this potentially tens or hundreds of thousands of times, so would like to avoid a for loop if possible.

I should possibly note that (I don't think) `lapply` won't work with this because it will check every vector index against the current list and vice versa with 'apply'.

I think that I could save a new list with the two start and end indices and dataframes being sublists (i.e. `mylist <- list(list(starts[1], ends[1], df1), list(starts[2])...`), but I wonder if there's anything cleaner?

Comment: What is the criteria for a match within one set of start/end points and a table. In other words, forget about looping over the full list for a minute, what does the optimal solution look like using a single start/end point and table?

Comment: So what I'm currently doing is testing the 'start' and 'end' positions against both the start and end positions for each region in the table - so that if we have a start position `x <- 17`, I'd test for where both `x >= start` and `x <= end`, giving me a TRUE/FALSE vector of the same size as the number of rows of the table. Doing the same with an end position then allows me to see which region(s) `x` and `y` overlap.

Comment: When I know what regions are TRUE between `x` and `y`, I can use those row indices to pull out the region names from the third column of the table. The final answer, if it contains multiple regions, will be pasted together with ';' as a separator so that it can all fit into a single cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - in case anyone comes across this in future, setting `X` in `lapply` to `1:length(list/vector)` works perfectly.

With my example above, instead of the for loop, try:

```
lapply(X = 1:length(mylist), 
       FUN = function(n) { mylist[[n]]
                                      [which(starts[n] >= mylist[[n]][, 1] & 
                                             starts[n] <= mylist[[n]][,2]):
                                       which(ends[n] >= mylist[[n]][, 1] &
                                             ends[n] <= mylist[[n]][, 2]), 3] } )
```